# the debian administrator book, install

Tags: software-center, ebooks

I have downloaded the book in the software center, but I cant open it, what do I do? I have installed calibre, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Calibre
2. Click the *Add Books* icon -> *Add Books from a single directory*
3. Browse to your book, select it and click the **Open** button.
4. Select your book from the middle pane (you can use the search box to help you find it) and click the *View* icon to open the book for reading in Calibre.

Comment: thanks, I just thought since there was a icon for the book I could use that

Comment: You can do that from the terminal, but it's much easier to do if you import all of your books into your Calibre library. Then Calibre will automatically bookmark the last page you read so the next time you open the book it will open it at that page, and you can also search for books in your Calibre library by author, title, etc.